# The order of execution of the same hook implementation in two different modules

Tags: 7

I need to create two custom modules in Drupal 7. The two custom modules will implement the same hook. How can I guarantee the order of execution for the two custom module? I mean module1 will run first then module2 OR the reverse order?

Comment: This has been answered already > http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37674/how-drupal-decide-execution-order-of-same-hook-in-different-modules

Comment: print something in both hooks.and run that code.check which one came first.

Comment: That answer is for D6 I think - D7 has [`module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7).

Comment: @Andy why don't you put this as an answer? Seems it indeed **is** a valid answer.

Comment: @Mołot I voted to close as duplicate instead (:

Comment: @Andy Good move, added my vote to yours.