# Return value on a submit handler

Tags: hooks

Below is a hook from the LinkedIn Integration module.

Then I have a hook form alter in my module and it's all setup and ready to go to call a submit handler.

When the user goes to authorize LinkedIn, and come back, I want to fire some my code.

The question is I don't know what states or values are after it comes back. I tried this

```
function my_module_form_link($form,$form_state, $uid)
{
  dpm($form_state['values']); 
}
```

but it did not return anything

```
function linkedin_user_enable_form($form, $form_state, $uid) {
  $form = array();
  $form['#user'] = $uid;
  $form['#action'] = url('linkedin/token/' . $uid);
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Go to LinkedIn'),
    '#suffix' => '<p class="description">' . t('You will be taken to the LinkedIn website in order to complete the process.') . '</p>',
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the linkedin module [source code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/linkedin/tree/linkedin.inc?h=7.x-1.x),  there's some ways that can run code on the way back (but only when are logging-in, it seems).

**When they are logging-in:**

1. `hook_linkedin_external_login`: if they don't already have an account and will be asked to register.
2. `hook_linkedin_tie_external_login`: if they already have an account and will be logged-in using that account.

**When they are associating a linkedin account:**

- *I do not see any hooks or any stable way of running code in this case.*

**Here's an example on how to hook into `hook_linkedin_external_login`:**

In your `mymodule.module` file:

```
function mymodule_linkedin_external_login($uid) {
  // do something
}
```

But you'll have to be careful since `linkedin_auth_linkedin_external_login` does a `drupal_goto()` so you'll have to have your module hook called first, so that your function doesn't get skipped. See [how drupal decide execution order of same hook in different modules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37674/how-drupal-decide-execution-order-of-same-hook-in-different-modules)

Comment: This isn't for login, it is for when they auth in their profile.

Comment: You mean when linking their linked-in account through their Drupal profile? In that case, that's my second section above, there's no obvious way to trigger code or hook onto something.

Comment: Take a look at linkedin.inc module_invoke_all('linkedin_external_login', $uid); that calls a function in linkedin_auth.module function linkedin_auth_linkedin_external_login($uid) can I do anything with that?

Comment: Yes this is the first hook I mention in my answer, I've added an example on how to use that hook.

Comment: I tried using using this, but when I login, I don't get a message. function module_linkedin_external_login($form,$form_state) {
    global $user;
    $account = user_load($user->uid);
    drupal_set_message(t('Hello - Login Worked'));
}  ALSO I set the weight to -1

Comment: Try using both hooks then, this one is for when you don't already have a Drupal account. The other is used when you already have an account in Drupal.