# Changing the weight of my custom module does not affect the order of execution of my hook implementation

Tags: 9, distributions

I use the `goalgorilla/open_social` profile which brings in open social with its various modules. Inside its `social_user.module` there is a standard `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` implementation which I temporarily edit and prepend `echo 'social';`. I also have a custom module `my_custom_module` with the same `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` implementation which simply contains `echo 'custom';`.

My problem is that no matter what, I cannot get my custom module's echo to run after the open social's one. The higher weight of my custom module does not seem to affect anything. So far I've done the following:

1. `module_set_weight('my_custom_module', 9999);`
2. Confirmed in `core.extension.yml` that:

```
social: 0
social_user: 0
my_custom_module: 9999
```

3. Installed https://www.drupal.org/project/modules_weight and confirmed the expected weights at `admin/config/system/modules-weight`.

Where should I look at next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what order are implementations of the of same hook done from different modules invoked?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37674/in-what-order-are-implementations-of-the-of-same-hook-done-from-different-module)

Comment: This didn't change from D7 to D8+. There's also an example in the docs: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/9.3.x

Comment: @leymannx: No it does not. I am not asking about what the weight does or how to change it.

Comment: So you are not asking how to have your hook to be called after every other module's hook? What are you asking then? 

Comment: My problem is in the title. I know what the weight does, how to change it, and what effect it has. Yet in this case it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah that's why we are suggesting other ways to achieve that.

Comment: Using that method to check which `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` implementation is invoked first is the wrong way. If both the hooks are adding a form element to the form, it's sufficient to check which form element appears first in the hook.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3120298). Didn't read it because there are most times better solutions by adding a callback to the form build which gets executed at the right time: `#process`, `#after_build` or `#pre_render`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue recently and figured out that some modules (like [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) in my case) uses [hook_module_implements_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.9.x) to change the order of execution.