# How to avoid custom module hook_node_presave being overriden by a profile module node_presave

Tags: entities, hooks, 7

I'm willing to override a value before it get saved in database.
The same value is already overriden by commons_trusted_contacts module using hook_node_presave.

So my custom module hook_node_presave get overriden by commons_trusted_contacts_node_presave.
How do I let drupal know that he need to run my custom hook_node_presave after other hook node presave or to not override that single field value.

Below line being overridden :

`$wrapper->group_content_access->set(OG_CONTENT_ACCESS_PUBLIC);`

Answer (score 1):

The order of a module's hook invocation is determined by its weight. In Drupal 7 this set in the `weight` column in the system `table`.

This can be updated through SQL query by setting your module's weight to the heaviest (last) value.

```
# Update with the appropriate values for your install
drush sqlq "UPDATE {system} SET weight = [your_preferred_weight] WHERE type = 'module' AND name = '[your_module_name]"'
```

Or using a module like [Modules weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/modules_weight) if you need a UI.

See the [Drupal.org documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/110238) for more info..

Comment: Thanks for pointing doc that helped me to come out with the answer bellow by using hook_module_implements_alter. Switching hook order was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing [drupal.org documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7.x), It's was helpfull.

I ended up using `hook_module_implements_alter` which better suited to my situation than changing the module weight.

So I've changed the order in which my hooks are triggered than changing module weight.

`/**
* Implements hook_module_implements_alter
*/
function glue_site_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if (($hook == 'node_presave') && isset($implementations['my_module'])) {
    //dpm($implementations, 'before');
    $module = 'my_module';
    $group = array($module => $implementations[$module]);
    unset($implementations[$module]);
    $implementations = $implementations + $group;
  }
}`

Reading [Adjusting module weight: what are the risks and things to look out for?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7836/adjusting-module-weight-what-are-the-risks-and-things-to-look-out-for)  also helped me to understand behavior of changing module weight.